# Get and Set Methods in C++ OOP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, enums

In my computer science class I have an enum value in a header file and I'm having troubles with the get and set functions. I'm quite new to C++. This is part of my header file:

```
enum class SchoolType {
    Elementary = 1,
    Secondary = 2
};

class School : public Institution
{
    public:
        // There are a couple more values here

    SchoolType GetSchoolType();
    void SetSchoolType(SchoolType typeSchool);
};
```

And this is part of my .cpp file:

```
SchoolType GetTypeSchool()
{
    return this->_typeSchool;
}
void SetTypeSchool(SchoolType typeSchool)
{

}
```

But 'this' brings up an error and says that 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function. How can I get that function to work? My computers teacher told me that that is how I should code the get function but I still don't understand, is there something that I'm doing wrong in the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the .cpp file, you should have:

```
SchoolType School::GetSchoolType() {
    return this->_typeSchool;
}
void School::SetSchoolType(SchoolType typeSchool) {
    // Insert code here...
}
```

Basically, in C++ you need to specify what class the function is part of (in this case, `School`) when defining the member functions, or else the compiler doesn't see it as being part of any class. You also need to keep your method names consistent (`GetSchoolType` vs `GetTypeSchool`).